# How should I transform a featureset (15000 variables) that is mostly presence/absence, but present values are lognormal distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to learn machine learning and have a nice featureset with a binary classification.

The dataset is 15000 variables and 2500 data rows. For every data row, almost all variables are 0, and roughly 20 are non-zero. The values of these 20 are lognormal distributed over the whole variable set (i.e. the 50000 non-zero values in the 15000*2500 matrix are lognormal distributed).

The question is, what should I do with the featureset? The blunt way would be to transform it into purely presence/absence. However I wonder whether there is any information in the relative intensities within the values. I have considered "doubling" the dataset (copying the 15000 variables into 15000 presence/absence + 15000 logarithmized/NA variables).

(For the record, even without any transformation, KNN and Random Forest models can predict halfway decently.)

Comment: How do you know the non-zero values have a lognormal distribution?

Comment: `hist(log(matrix.trainingset[matrix.trainingset > 0]))`

Comment: Thanks. Rather than assert that you have the positive values being lognormally distributed, you'd probably be better saying something like "from looking at histograms of the logs, the non-zero values seem to be reasonably consistent with being lognormally distributed". or something like that.

Comment: So 20 out of 15000 values for each row **not** missing! You could try to simply set all missing to -1 and run RF. Otherwise unsupervised method may be needed. I had a smaller data set with 1000 skewed signal strengths readings to each of 110 nearby access points. 95% of signal strength readings were 0, because AP was too far away. I transformed signal strength to dB (a non-skewed unit) and compressed with PCA to 5 PCs and ran some supervised models on top. So maybe you can fix skewedness also and reduce 15000 variables to some ~500 maybe. Remember to save rotation matrix to make predictions